# What are the absolute minimum packages needed for Debian Wheezy

Tags: embedded, debian

I want to install the bare minimum of Debian Wheezy on an embedded controller with 128Mb flash.
So far I found the nice debootstrap method for installing, like described [here](http://www.yoovant.com/debian-wheezy-rootfs/). This end up with 157Mb disk usage after adding ssh.
Someone created a nice image for RasPi with have 118Mb, see [here](http://www.linuxsystems.it/raspbian-wheezy-armhf-raspberry-pi-minimal-image/).
Additionally I tried shrinking by this guideline [here](https://wiki.debian.org/ReduceDebian), but it also dont succeed much.

Currently the controller is running with EmDebian Grip occupies 79Mb with 182 packages installed. But under Wheezy it needs much more.
So what packages are the absolute minimum needed?

Thanks
  Achim